# C - Non Sensible result of if-else statements

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

I changed the conditions in several ways, But always the second condition is true by compiler.

```
int signf(int a);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter A Number :\n");
    int i = scanf("%d", &i);    
    signf(i);
    return 0;
}

int signf(int a)
{
    if(a<0)
    {
        printf("Your Number is Negative\n");
    }
    else if((a>=0)&&(a<10))
    {
        printf("Your Number has One Digit\n");
    }
    else if((a>=10)&&(a<100))
    {
        printf("Your Number has Two Digits\n");
    }
    else if((a>=100)&&(a<1000))
    {
        printf("Your Number has Three Digits\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your Number is Huge!\n");
    }
    printf("This is End!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It always shows up: Your Number has One Digit, The condition is always true whether I enter 8 or 56 or 849.
What's wrong with this code? I expected work fine, But doesn't.

Comment: The `>=` checks are entirely superfluous. That condition is always true when checking it. If it weren't, we'd have entered a previous branch and never gotten to testing it!

Answer (score 3):

`int i = scanf("%i", &i);` is an abuse of `scanf` - didn't your compiler warn you?

`scanf` returns the number of arguments that were successfully read, which is 1 in your case assuming a successful read. And that has one digit! (Yes, it's always a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`.)

A good line by line debugger would not have thrown you off the scent as your question implied - the problem is *not* in `signf`.

Comment: In short (and I mention this because it's a critically important point for debugging), the value of `i` after `scanf()` was never verified against the actual value that was input.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = scanf("%i",&i);// wrong because your input in variable i is modified by return of function scanf.
```

Use this instead

```
scanf("%i",&i);
```

Check this article:
[return value of scanf and printf](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-values-of-printf-and-scanf-in-c-cpp/)

Moreover, please use %d instead of %i.
Check the link of the article to know the difference
[difference between %d and %i behavior in scanf](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-d-format-specifier-c-language/)

Comment: sorry sir , I had manipulated the code , And it was %d at first . Still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir , I guessed it may not be if statements but scanf but couldn't fix it . I haven't read C Libraries well yet ... I'm newbie . Thanks a lot